# Linux: Find with Grep and CP. Need assistance with the modifier to preserve directory structure

Tags: linux, grep, command-line-interface, cp

The issue:
We have hundreds of folders, each with hundreds of images.  We need to copy the first 5 images into a destination folder.

This is the command I've managed to construct:

```
find . -name '000[0-5]*' -exec cp --parents {} /volume1/WORKING/Covers/disk6/africa{} \;
```

returns this error message:

```
cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory
```

I can't seem to find the correct modifier.  What am I missing?

Thanking you kindly

Comment: [rsync](https://www.mankier.com/1/rsync) could probably do it.

Comment: Thank you/.  I'm reading the manual file.  I'll try to figure it out.  Much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Suggesting to try:

```
 cp $(find . -type f -name '000[0-5]*') /volume1/WORKING/Covers/disk6/africa
```